# Is it legal to take the icon/graphic file found online to use in software project?

Tags: licensing, legal

For example, like this icon website: http://www.iconspedia.com/

There is a lot icon there, (I just can't draw myself, I am not good at it.....), I wonder if is OK to use them in my software project?

Will the type of project make difference?

i.e Open Source Application, Commercial Application, Free Download Application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Free icons** does imply they are free to use.

The [FAQ](http://www.iconspedia.com/faq/) says to check the license agreement in each individual pack, some may require crediting the artis or be under creative commons or similar.

Unfortunately most of the licenses use rather uncertain phrases - like free for "non-commercial use" or "free for personal use". It's very difficult to decide exactly what these mean - which is why licenses like the GPL contain a lot of text and some very carefully chosen words.

But if this is just for a project for yourself that you aren't selling it seems that mot of these sets would be fine.

Comment: I just want to write a random metro application and publish it with some of their icon, it seems more diffcult now.....

Comment: If there is a particular set you like email the author and ask

Answer (score 1):

The type of project makes a difference as does the terms of the site you got the image from. Some sites do not allow for usage of images without paid licensing, some without attribution, and some are entirely free, local country of origin's laws aside. It can also depend on the project. Some are available for use in applications made by students for educational, noncommercial purposes. Others are available only for commercial applications. It all depends on the photos or pictures in question.

In the case of Iconspedia, each icon has a listing for what license applies to it. It appears most are non-commercial usage only from a cursory perusal.

Comment: Ahh... it seems more complicate than I thought now...